# How can I use a decay envelope with nAudio signal generator?

Tags: c#, naudio

I'm in the process of learning c# and NAudio. In my project, I need to play a series of short tones using a decay envelope. It looks like the ADSR Envelope sample provider will do this, but I can't seem to make it work with the signal generator. When I set the release time, I just get a constant tone.
Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong?
Here's a very simple console app that I'm trying to use to test this:

```
    class Program
    {
        public SignalGenerator wg;
        public IWavePlayer driverOut;
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            // Init Audio
            var driverOut = new WaveOutEvent();
            var wg = new SignalGenerator();
            var adsr = new AdsrSampleProvider(wg.ToMono());
            wg.Type = SignalGeneratorType.Sin;
            adsr.AttackSeconds = 0;
            adsr.ReleaseSeconds = (float)1;
            wg.Take(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(500));
            driverOut.Init(wg);
            wg.Frequency = 500  ;
            wg.Gain = 0.1;  
            
            driverOut.Play();
            Thread.Sleep(3000);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you can trigger the **Release** phase by calling `adsr.Stop()`. This makes sense as the release phase on a keyboard happens after you release the key, but it's not particularly intuitive.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var wg = new SignalGenerator
        {
            Type = SignalGeneratorType.Sin,
            Frequency = 500,
            Gain = 0.1
        };

        var adsr = new AdsrSampleProvider(wg.ToMono())
        {
            AttackSeconds = 0.3f,
            ReleaseSeconds = 0.3f
        };
            
        using (var driverOut = new WaveOutEvent())
        {
            driverOut.Init(adsr);
            driverOut.Play();

            Thread.Sleep(500);

            adsr.Stop();

            while (driverOut.PlaybackState == PlaybackState.Playing) { }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Unfortunately, this is doing exactly what I was seeing before. I can get the attack to fade in the signal, but release isn't fading it out. I set the Take value to 5 seconds, and the ADSR release to 1 second, and the sound just cuts off at the end. It doesn't fade out.

Comment: Yes, I see what you mean

Comment: Taking a look at the NAudio source code, this line looks a little odd - https://github.com/naudio/NAudio/blob/master/NAudio/Wave/SampleProviders/AdsrSampleProvider.cs#L26